# Whats the error refer to connect xively using master api key? SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)

Tags: python, xively

I use the below code and put a right Master Api key from the setting of personal xively site but the result is "SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)" . don't know why it occurred.

> from time import localtime, strftime
>
> import time
>
> import requests
>
> import random
>
> ## Base URL for the requests
>
> url = 'https://api.xively.com'
>
> ## Replace with your master API key and feed IDs of your devices
>
> MASTER_API_KEY = '***********'
>
> feed_ID_1 = '******'
>
> feed_ID_2 = '******'
>
> feed_ID_3 = '******'
>
> ## Function for updating all channels of a device using the requests library
>
> ## :param feed_id: feed ID of a device
>
> ## :param temperature: temperature value to be updated to a channel
>
> ## :param humidity: humidity value to be updated to a channel
>
> ## :param lux: lux value to be updated to a channel
>
> def update_channels(feed_id, temperature, humidity, light):
>
> url_feed =url + '/v2/feeds/' + str(feed_id) + '.json'     headers = {'X-ApiKey':
>   str(MASTER_API_KEY)}
>
> payload =   '{  \
>           "version":"1.0.0",    \
>            "datastreams" : [ {  \
>             "id" : "humidity",  \
>               "current_value" : '+str(humidity)+'   \
>             },  \
>             {   \
>             "id" : "light", \
>             "current_value" : '+str(light)+'        \
>             },  \
>             {   \
>               "id" : "temperature", \
>             "current_value" : '+str(temperature)+'  \
>             }   \
>           ] \       } '\
>
> try: 
>   r = requests.put(url=url_feed, headers=headers, data=payload)
>   print (strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", localtime()))
>   print (payload)
>   print (r.text)
>   print (r.status_code)
>     except Exception as e:
>   print(e)
>
> ## Loop for updating 3 devices with random values from a given ranges
>
> while True:
>   update_channels(feed_ID_1,random.uniform(20.0,22.0),random.uniform(50.0,51.0),random.uniform(320.0,325.0))
>   update_channels(feed_ID_2,random.uniform(22.0,24.0),random.uniform(51.0,52.0),random.uniform(325.0,330.0))
>   update_channels(feed_ID_3,random.uniform(24.0,26.0),random.uniform(52.0,53.0),random.uniform(330.0,335.0))
>   time.sleep(1)

Comment: on your exception put the following:

except Exception as e:
print(e)

In order to get a better view on why requests is raising an exception, then update your question with the result from the exception, because most likely is not a connection failed error

Comment: ok done it. here the error: SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645

Comment: Refer to this answer then, the problem might be in ssl certificate of the api you are trying to access http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503206/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-python