# TransportError: HTTPSConnectionPool error calling Google Cloud Speech API from Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-speech-api

I downloaded Google Cloud SDK by following https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-debian-ubuntu . 
And I downloaded Google Speech API by following 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/cloud-client  .
When I run  python transcribe.py resources/audio.raw,
the error happens.
I got an error,TransportError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='accounts.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /o/oauth2/token (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)'),))
)>)

Traceback is

```html
E1019 18:46:20.868555489    3813 plugin_credentials.c:74]    Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/credentials.pyx.pxi", line 154, in grpc._cython.cygrpc.plugin_get_metadata (src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.c:7054)
  File "/home/pi/py2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/_plugin_wrapping.py", line 106, in __call__
    AuthMetadataPluginCallback(wrapped_cygrpc_callback))
  File "/home/pi/py2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 73, in __call__
    callback(self._get_authorization_headers(context), None)
  File "/home/pi/py2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 61, in _get_authorization_headers
    headers)
  File "/home/pi/py2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/auth/credentials.py", line 121, in before_request
    self.refresh(request)
  File "/home/pi/py2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/oauth2/credentials.py", line 117, in refresh
    self._client_secret))
  File "/home/pi/py2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 189, in refresh_grant
    response_data = _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)
  File "/home/pi/py2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 104, in _token_endpoint_request
    method='POST', url=token_uri, headers=headers, body=body)
  File "/home/pi/py2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 115, in __call__
    raise exceptions.TransportError(exc)
TransportError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='accounts.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /o/oauth2/token (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)'),))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transcribe.py", line 94, in <module>
    transcribe_file(args.path)
  File "transcribe.py", line 52, in transcribe_file
    response = client.recognize(config, audio)
  File "/home/pi/py2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/gapic/speech/v1/speech_client.py", line 201, in recognize
    return self._recognize(request, options)
  File "/home/pi/py2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 452, in inner
    return api_caller(api_call, this_settings, request)
  File "/home/pi/py2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 438, in base_caller
    return api_call(*args)
  File "/home/pi/py2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/gax/api_callable.py", line 376, in inner
    return a_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/py2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/gax/retry.py", line 127, in inner
    ' classified as transient', exception)
google.gax.errors.RetryError: RetryError(Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient, caused by <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNAUTHENTICATED, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/credentials.pyx.pxi", line 154, in grpc._cython.cygrpc.plugin_get_metadata (src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.c:7054)
  File "/home/pi/py2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/_plugin_wrapping.py", line 106, in __call__
    AuthMetadataPluginCallback(wrapped_cygrpc_callback))
  File "/home/pi/py2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 73, in __call__
    callback(self._get_authorization_headers(context), None)
  File "/home/pi/py2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 61, in _get_authorization_headers
    headers)
  File "/home/pi/py2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/auth/credentials.py", line 121, in before_request
    self.refresh(request)
  File "/home/pi/py2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/oauth2/credentials.py", line 117, in refresh
    self._client_secret))
  File "/home/pi/py2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 189, in refresh_grant
    response_data = _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)
  File "/home/pi/py2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 104, in _token_endpoint_request
    method='POST', url=token_uri, headers=headers, body=body)
  File "/home/pi/py2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 115, in __call__
    raise exceptions.TransportError(exc)
TransportError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='accounts.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /o/oauth2/token (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)'),))
)>)
```

I installed module can be used https  to ubuntu,so I really cannnot understand why this error happens.Authentication of Google Cloud API is ok,so I do not know this is for what kind of error.How should I fix this?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on?

Comment: @snakecharmerb it is Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) LTS

Comment: Poosibly relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/41221454/5320906

Answer (score 0):

It looks a `grpcio` issue that's causing the error. I suggest installing the latest version the Cloud Speech API client library (which specifies its required version of `grpcio`) and try again. Rather than downloading it from GH, I suggest using `pip install` instead.

**"Hello World" s2t-demo.py example** (Py2&3 compatible):

```
from __future__ import print_function
from google.cloud import speech

# Py2 vs. 3 library compatibility
recogcfg = speech.RecognitionConfig if hasattr(
        speech, 'RecognitionConfig') else speech.enums.RecognitionConfig

# build request metadata
FILE = 'gs://YOUR_BUCKET/AUDIO_FILE.wav'
body = {
    'audio': {'uri': FILE},
    'config': {
        'language_code': 'en-US',
        'encoding': recogcfg.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    },
}

# call Speech-to-Text API to transcribe text from specified audio file
S2T = speech.SpeechClient()
rsp = S2T.recognize(**body).results[0].alternatives[0]
print('** %.2f%% confident of this transcript of %r:\n\t%r' % (
        rsp.confidence*100., FILE, rsp.transcript))
```

**Recommended steps** (recommend using a virtualenv):

1. `gcloud auth application-default login` - setup credentials
2. `pip install -U pip google-cloud-speech` - update `pip` and install client library
3. `pip list` - confirm `google-cloud-speech` v1.3.4+ and `grpcio` 1.41.1+
4. `gsutil cp AUDIO_FILE.wav gs://YOUR_BUCKET` - copy audio file to Cloud Storage
5. `python s2t-demo.py` - run app and see audio file transcription

**Example output:**

```
$ python s2t-demo.py
** 93.05% confident of this transcript of 'gs://bucket/text.wav':
        'Google headquarters in Mountain View unveiled the new Android phone at the Consumer Electronics Show Sundar pichai said in his keynote that users love their new Android phones'
```

The code sample works for both Python 2 and 3 in case you want to upgrade sooner than later.